# How to add a python project to an azure repository?

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-repos

I am trying to add a new folder to an azure repository.  This main folder has a sub-folder with a python project.  When I add the main folder, all sub-folders upload successfully, except the python folder.  This folder appears in the color black in the azure repository, and when I click on it to view its content, only a long alpha-numeric string appears in the editor.

How can I have the python folder appear normally in azure? I would like to be able to navigate the contents of this folder in the azure interface in the same way as windows explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which way you used to add a new folder to an azure repository ，but I can successfully add a main folder with the subfolder which has a python project to an azure repository by using the git command. You can try this way as follows .

git clone {your repository url} -> cd {cloned repository folder}

Add the folder you need to your local repo folder

git add . -> git commit -m "xx" -> git push origin master

[image]

Finally, you will see in the UI that a main folder with the subfolder which has a python project was successfully added to the azure repository.

[image]